# cannot install node modules in angular project

Tags: angular, node-modules

When i am trying to install new angular project using 'ng new projectname' command , node_modules folder and package-lock.json file is not showing in the project folder.

I tried to install node_modules manually using command 'npm install', also tried to update angular and node using command but none of them worked. I am using angular version 15.2.0 and node version 16.14.0 .

Comment: At least share logs so that we can understand what you are trying and where it’s getting failed

Comment: Do you have `angular-cli` installed?  Do you get error messages when you run commands?  You need to provide more information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.